# Why does backbone url prepend a question mark?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a url like:

`www.hello.com/something#one/two/three`

that becomes

`www.hello.com/something?#one/two/three`

when I click a button that pops out a modal. This was working perfectly fine before but after some routing changes, when I click the modal, the entire page refreshes, the url gets a question mark inserted and nothing happens. Then when I click the button again everything works fine but that question mark is always before the hash no matter where I route from then on.

when I navigate somewhere outside backbone's routing and go back to the hash routing, it happens again.
What is causing this question mark to appear? Nothing changed except the routing where I changed

`":category/:categoryItem" : "showItem",
 ":category/:categoryItem/:a/:b": "showDetails",`

to

`"permanent/:category/:categoryItem" : "showItem",
 "temporary/:category/:categoryItem/:a/:b": "showDetails",`

Comment: seems like backbone thinks your parameters are a query. Check the actual href on the links

Comment: @raam86 Nothing there is wrapped in an anchor :/ Plus I don't have any anchors that have a ? in them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was with a button in a form. Had to use preventDefault on the event.